# What camera size in Blender pixels would a profile picture be?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I really need to know. I use 2.79b, and a MacBook Pro (I highly doubt that's necessary, however).

Comment: there is no difference between "blender pixels" and regular pixels. If your profile picture is 256x256px, then thats what your render size needs to be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Blender

Comment: Yeah, gonna delete this post